# Music tune to note decoder

Tags: android, osx, music-recognition, transcription

I'm looking for music note decoder for Mac based on the recorded song.

So basically the software/app which can transcribe the music into sheet music.

I'm considering app for OS X or smart devices based on iOS or Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few which I've tried:

- [Pitch Genie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.PitchGenie) for Android

  > Transcribe sound into sheet music that can be saved and edited.

  Not great for multiple instruments. Sometimes it crashes. See [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/1vei8u/).
- [Music to notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bzgames.musicalair&hl=en) for Android

  > Listens using your microphone and see the pitches that it hears to the common musical staff.
- [Accurate Music To Note Decoder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.musictranscription) for Android

  > Transcribe music and see its notes instantly.
- [Note Recognizer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nl.robertloeberdevelopment) for Android

  > The app analyses the pitch frequency that you sing or play, and gives the corresponding note name.

I've tested above and they work for simple piano, but they didn't work for more complex instrumental music such as [this cello tune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2RvGJ-HiCDE). So it's better to transcribe them using desktop app, but it'll require a lot of more work of editing of more complex pieces.

Here are even more advanced apps:

- [Neuratron's AudioScore](http://www.neuratron.com/audioscore.htm) for Windows & Mac ([Demo](http://www.neuratron.com/asdemo.htm) link)

  > Create scores from MP3s and CD tracks! Using the most intelligent technology available AudioScore Ultimate is able to convert up to 16 instruments / notes playing at a time into multiple staves, with up to 4 voices per staff.
  >
  > The result can be imported into [Sibelius](http://www.avid.com/sibelius) and played along with the scores or for further adjustment.

  See video review: [Audio Score 8 Review- Music Ed Minute- E07](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a03R30IjSZ4)